# parsing php multi array input field

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using multi-array input field to store data in HTML of CakePHP 3 project

```
<input name="media[0]['text']">
<input name="media[0]['color']" ?>
<input name="media[1]['text']" ?>
<input name="media[1]['color']"?>

and so on...
```

Using PHP to store the input field value to database by JSON encoding media array

```
$column_field = json_encode($this->request->getData('media'));
```

which stores in database JSON string like

```
[{"'text'":"example text 1","'color'":"#ff00ff"},{"'text'":"example text 2","'color'":"#00ff99"}]
```

again when I need the data I decode the string to convert back to php array

```
$data = (array)json_decode($column_field);
```

on `debug($data)`, it gives

```
[
        (int) 0 => object(stdClass) {
                'text' => 'example text 1'
                'color' => '#ff00ff'
        },
        (int) 1 => object(stdClass) {
                'text' => 'example text 2'
                'color' => '#00ff99'
        }
]
```

then I loop through each array element

```
foreach($data as $item) {
   debug($item->text);
}
```

But it returns null.

changing array object to array

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
  $item = (array)$item;
  debug($item);
}
```

gives

```
[
        ''text'' => 'example text 1',
        ''color'' => '#ff00ff',
]
```

and this is accessed by `$item["'text'"]`

**How to parse it properly to access it either `$item['text']` or `$item->text`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input name="media[0][text]">
instead of
<input name="media[0]['text']">
```

If you really need to name your field "media[0]['text']" you can access it by `$item->{'text'}`

Comment: Thanks, I want the first one `<input name="media[0][text]">`